# Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 'Trusty Tahr' frozen on ubuntu opening screen

Tags: system-installation

I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 'Trusty Tahr' from Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.  The installation was executed as an Ubuntu upgrade within Ubuntu 12.04.  The problem is the screen freezes prior to login.  The Ubuntu logo appears and that computer freezes.  The disk light is not flickering, which suggests that nothing is happening.

I have attempted the Unity re-install using ctrl+Alt+F2, which is suggested in another post.

I am using a 64 bit Lenovo Thinkpad with 16 GB of RAM.

Comment: If you press the escape ('Esc') key as the Ubuntu logo appears, you should see text scrolling down the screen to show what the Ubuntu is doing as it starts, looking at this should give a better indication of the reason for the problem.

Comment: Hi ivorsmashman, I did as you suggested 9engaging esc key while Ubuntu logo loads).  There is a failure of the virtual machine monitor, which I don't think is important as I am running vmware with windows.  However, the machine just freezes and does not continue with its loading.